# What is "Migrating Blockchain Version"?

Tags: monerod, blockchain

I just got the recent version of bitmonero wallet winx64 v0-10-1-0. It says `Migrating blockchain from DB version 0 to 1` with the total number of blocks being 1,142,544 (data.mdb is 9.67 GB).

What is the "migration" process? Is it having to completely export the blockchain to raw data then import it to a new data.mdb?

I've been running monerod.exe for over 24 hours and I don't see any export data or raw blockchain file so I would like to confirm that progress is being made somewhere. It is not a SSD hard drive and it's consuming resources to the point that my machine is out of service until it is done working.

What is it doing and how can I confirm progress is being made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Jolly Mort's comment, I can answer this question now.

Running it with `monerod --log-level=1` is much more verbose in both terminal and the log file at `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\bitmonero.log`

The logs explain the process a bit more in depth:
`2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 Migrating blockchain from DB version 0 to 1 - this may take a while:
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 updating blocks, hf_versions, outputs, txs, and spent_keys tables...
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 Total number of blocks: 1142544
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 block migration will update block_heights, block_info, and hf_versions...
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 migrating block_heights:
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702   block_heights already migrated
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 migrating block info:
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702   block_info already migrated
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 migrating hf_versions:
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702   hf_versions already migrated
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 deleting old indices:
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702   old indices already deleted
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.636702 migrating txs and outputs:
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.652302 [check_and_resize_for_batch] checking DB size
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.652302 [get_estimated_batch_size] m_height: 1142544  block_start: 1142044  block_stop: 1142543
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.823902 average block size across recent 500 blocks: 5814
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.823902 estimated average block size for batch: 5814
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.823902 calculated batch size: 130815000
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.823902 increase size: 536870912
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.823902 DB map size:     12884901888
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.823902 Space used:      10393010176
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.839502 Space remaining: 2491891712
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.839502 Size threshold:  130815000
2017-Jan-02 04:24:09.855102 Percent used: 0.8066  Percent threshold: 0.8000`

At the bottom of the terminal, though not in the log file, it displays `827000 / 1142544` which I am assuming is the number of blocks migrated out of the total number of blocks in my database. This is exactly what I was looking for and it means that the migration process is much faster for me than trying to sync the blockchain all over again. I can see it updating and it's currently at `830000 / 1142544`.

It looks something like this:
[image: screenshot of monerod log-level=1]

Side note: If you shut down by pressing Ctrl+c and then X out the window, it will say
`2017-Jan-02 04:48:05.138644 [node] Stop signal sent
2017-Jan-02 04:56:25.103922 Got control signal 2. Exiting without saving...`

Ignore this as it does appear to save and resume where it left off. I've tested and confirmed that this is the case.

**Edit:** This took somewhere under two days to complete (I didn't pay attention to the exact time, which could have been a day and a half) and my blockchain data was about 102 days behind the ledger after migrating. As of today, the ledger has a total of over 991 days on it. So I'm guessing this was faster in my case than synchronizing the entire blockchain. I'm on a 2.10Ghz laptop running Win64 with 4GB RAM and, perhaps most relevant, HDD ([specs](https://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-mk5059gsxp-hard-drive-500-gb-internal-2-5-sata-300-5400-rpm-buffer-8-mb-series/specs/)) not SSD.

**Edit 2:** It may be better to just download the blockchain again after updating because it eventually got stuck on a blockchain around 23 days behind with a [bunch of errors](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/attempting-to-get-output-pubkey-by-global-index-but-key-does-not-exist) that it just would not get past for some reason. It ended up costing me a lot more time than it was worth.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the patience and a nice answer!

Comment: Couldn't have done it without you. I'm hoping this one will be useful for a lot of people who are updating. Especially if the GUI wallet brings in a lot of new users.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you had a version older than 0.10.x before. The LMDB database (data.mdb) format has changed a bit since the old one and it's being converted to the new one. You could also kill the process, delete the `\lmdb` folder and just sync with the network from scratch. During migration from 0.9.x to 0.10.x, many people did exactly that.

I believe the migration doesn't exactly make a full .raw and then back into LMBD. I'd expect it to be a on-the-fly conversion. Someone more familiar with inner workings of the conversion could hop in.

Just to understand, blockchain.raw is clean blocks data, as found on the network. It is the blockchain in its 'pure' form, containing only the raw blocks. Your node processes raw blocks and saves them into a database in a special way where some information is repeated for faster accessing. Along with the actual blockchain data it stores many other things calculated from the blockchain data, and this allows it to perform very fast operations such as scanning through blocks when refreshing your wallet, ensuring the data doesn't get corrupt if your computer restarts etc.

When you're converting, your HDD has to do both "read" and "write" in some "read-process-write" operation and that makes the needle go crazy. If you're syncing from the network, the "read" part you get from the network and your HDD has only "write" to do, while your CPU & memory handles the "process" part. That's why re-sync from scratch might be a better idea.

Comment: Yes I am making exactly the same migration from 0.9.x to 0.10.x. That's helpful info. I'm hoping that migrating it locally is still faster than downloading the blockchain all over again. I would like to find out the current progress if possible to try to get a good estimate and compare these methods.

Comment: If your computer has less than about 8GB RAM, it will probably be faster to resync from the network.

Comment: @iyrin also, you can do this to see progress: 1. stop the daemon by using `ctrl+c` keystroke. 2. restart it with `monerod --log-level=1` - from #monero-dev on slack: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/518472/35874114/